# How to write this population with probability measure?

Tags: probability

$ S=\{A,C,G,T\}, b\in S $
$\mu(b=``A")=P_A, \mu(b=``C")=P_C, \mu(b=``G")=P_G, \mu(b=``T")=P_T $
$ P_x \in [0,1], \sum P_x=1 $

I want to describe a set with 4 possible elements, each come with a given proportion $\in[0,1]$, and the set is not empty.
How should I write this ?

Is there some way to simply it so that I do not need to repeat $ \mu(b=x)=P_X $ for 4 times ?

Comment: If you don't mind renaming the elements you could used indexes to write it only once: $\mu(b = A_i) = P_i$ with $S = \{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write it simply as discrete/atomic probability measure on $S$, i.e. set
\begin{equation}
\nu:=\sum_{X\in S}P_{X}\delta_{X}.
\end{equation}
Then for instance $\nu(\lbrace A\rbrace)=P_{A}=\mu(b=A)$.